# String takes any value in c# Visual Studio

Tags: c#

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string answer = (@"class SecLevel \n { \n static void Main()\n{Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");}}");
        if (textBox1.Text == answer)
        {
            MessageBox.Show( "Good!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: string doesn't take values

Comment: You might wanna include a question? Like how to I solve "XYZ" problem.

Comment: string answer = (@"class SecLevel \n { \n static void Main()\n{Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");}}") this line is error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the "Hello World!" you need to escape the ",

do this instead:

```
            "class SecLevel \\n { \\n static void Main()\\n{Console.WriteLine(\"Hello World!\");}}"
```